# How to get value cell by name in click event?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have got DatagridView with click event inside that I try to get value of another cell from selected row:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    string status = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

}
```

It works, but how can I get value by name column like this:

```
string status = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["status"].Value.ToString();
```

I have column with name `status`, but ut says me that there is not column

[image]

Comment: Code works.  Do you not have a column named "status"?

Comment: Is it right? `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["status"].Value.ToString();`? I thought `Cells` takes only index

Comment: Look at intellisense.  It has two options: integer and string.

Comment: Does your data source have a "status" column name?

Comment: Yes, see pic attachment in question

Comment: That does not tell me your data source has the same column name.

Comment: What do you mean source code?

Comment: If your data source for the grid is a DataTable, the DataPropertyName will map that column to the DataTable's column.  Your grid has a column name of "status", so the code you posted should work.  Since you claim it isn't, maybe it's because the data source isn't mapped correctly.  You didn't document your data source.

Comment: Youare  right, problem was in model. It was necessary to do clear project